# How to get a list of objects from a JSON format

Tags: java, json

I am currently creating java objects with my current JSON format which looks something like this:

```
{ 
    "_id" : "45", 
    "longitude" : "-0.203247", 
    "latitude" : "51.497843", 
    "timeDateOfUsage" : [
        "24/12/17 13:57:55", 
        "1", 
        "24/12/17 14:03:08", 
        "0", 
        "24/12/17 14:03:28", 
        "1", 
        "24/12/17 14:03:36", 
        "0", 
        "24/12/17 14:21:31", "0", 
        "24/12/17 14:21:40", 
        "1"
    ] 
}
```

I am now currently trying to convert a list of objects from the JSON to java objects. This is what I what I am trying to convert into java:

```
{ 
    "_id" : "3", 
    "longitude" : "3222", 
    "latitude" : "55", 
    "timeDateOfUsage" : [ 
        "02/11/17 13:30:35", 
        "1", 
        "02/11/17 13:30:45", 
        "1", 
        "02/11/17 13:30:51", 
        "0"
    ] 
}
{ 
    "_id" : "45", 
    "longitude" : "-0.203247", 
    "latitude" : "51.497843", 
    "timeDateOfUsage" : [
        "24/12/17 13:57:55", 
        "1", 
        "24/12/17 14:03:08", 
        "0", 
        "24/12/17 14:03:28", 
        "1", 
        "24/12/17 14:03:36", 
        "0", 
        "24/12/17 14:21:31", 
        "0", 
        "24/12/17 14:21:40", 
        "1"
    ] 
}
```

But I only seem to be getting the first object and not the rest (in this case, there;s a total of 2 objects). I am using  the Jackson library.

ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();

```
listofResponses.add( mapper.readValue(response,SensorResponse.class));
String output = "";
for(SensorResponse s : listofResponses){
    output = output + s.toString();
}
Log.d("dbserver", output);
```

I'm not sure as to why I am not able to the rest of the objects. And also by me doing `listofResponses.add( mapper.readValue(response,SensorResponse.class));`, would that automatically put each of the inidividual objects into the arraylist?

Comment: Use Gson . Easy and better

Comment: What ou have is not one valid JSON document. It is two JSON documents. Not sure where that came from, but you should change the design to either be able to read individual JSON documents, or to store these two objects inside a single JSON array. What is `response`? Where does it come from?

Comment: Use http://www.jsonschema2pojo.org/

Answer (score -1):

First save your string to a file, if that works for you. Otherwise use a different streaming method

Anyway if you have your json in a file like file.json, now do this

`JsonReader reader = Json.createReader(new FileReader("file.txt"));
    JsonStructure jsonst = reader.read();`

Of course you can replace FileReader with some other reader if you don't want to use a file

That's it, now you can parse through your 'jsonst' object. Ses this ref on how to do this

https://docs.oracle.com/middleware/1221/wls/WLPRG/java-api-for-json-proc.htm#WLPRG1062